# When should you normalize data?

Tags: normalization

I have 2 sets of prediction data and both sets have different scale, for example, one of it is in the range of 1e-3 value while the other is between 0-2, both have negative values. I would like to analyze the error of the data by taking the difference between the predicted value and actual value, ie f(x) and y|x.

I understand that i could normalize the data between 0 and 1 to compare the prediction error between both sets. But my question is should i normalize the predictions and actual value before i take the difference or after? Or does it not matter?

Comment: Are those sets related anyhow or those are different models using different data? What do you want to compare?

Comment: The same model is used to make these predictions, however since both data have different scale, one is of smaller scale compared to the other. I want to normalize it such that the data is comparable to each other

Comment: Why do they have different scales?